# Hashset 2d array

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array, hashset

I have a Hashset in which I store a list unique URLs. I want to make this a 2-d Hashset in which I have a unique list of URLs and a non unique number next to it. I then want to be able to search this list for a URL and the number associated with it. Below is an example of the list I want to create.

```
www.test1.com - 200
www.test2.com - 503
www.test3.com - 400
www.test4.com - 200
www.test5.com - 404
www.test6.com - 404
```

I then want to search for www.test2.com and get back 503. Is this possible with a Hashset? Or should I be looking at something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hashmap might be better suited for your case.

```
Map<String, Integer> urlHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
urlHashMap.put("www.test1.com", 200);
System.out.println(urlHashMap.get("www.test1.com")); //outputs 200
```

It provides a much simpler and easier way to get the values from the map.

Comment: Everyone was correct and it's solved my problem, choosing yours as the right answer as you also demonstrated how to access the value using the key. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I was able to help out.

Answer (score 3):

Try using HashMap with the URL being the key and the return code being the value. HashMap uses a HashSet behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that the proper data structure for you would be to build a **Dictionary \ HashMap** (all keys are unique: test1, test2, ..., and values do not have to be unique).

example:

```
HashMap<String,String> pairs = new HashMap<String,String>();

pairs.put("www.test1.com","404");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve what you want with a map instead,  as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("www.test1.com", 200);
map.put("www.test2.com", 503);
...and so on
```